# Arduino Python connect or disconnect message

Tags: python, if-statement, arduino

How could I make an if/else condition about the status of myAarduino? If the status of my Arduino is connected, I want to have a `Connected` Message. If not, message is `Disconnected`.

```
import serial
serialTransferRate = 115200
arduinoPort = '/dev/tty.usbmodem411'
def connectToArduino():
    arduino = serial.Serial(arduinoPort, serialTransferRate)
    if(arduino.timeout == None):
        print ("connected")
    else:
        print ("disconnected")
        arduino = connectToArduino()
```

*The error code below:*

```
 File "python", line 12, in <module>
  File "python", line 6, in connectToArduino
SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/tty.usbmodem411: [Errno 
2] No such file or directory: '/dev/tty.usbmodem411'
```

Comment: Badly indented Python code is nonsense. Please [edit] and correct your indentation.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: i added error message

Comment: Other than that line being indented at the same level as the previous one, make sure to not mix spaces with tabs. I don't think this is a useful question though, because it was caused by a typo. And SO already has a lot of questions about IndentationError and they all have the same answer.

Comment: I ve changed codes,so i have serial error.However,i want to have "disconnected" message.

Comment: You completely changed the question and invalidated the already posted answer. [This is not ok.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290746)

Answer (score 0):

The indentation should be like this, also you must use == for a comparison in an if statement and not = (which would be for assigning a value):

```
def connectToArduino():
    try:
        arduino = serial.Serial(arduinoPort, serialTransferRate)
    except:
        print 'disconnected'
    else:
        print 'connected'

arduino = connectToArduino()
```

The indentation in python is essential. Only things that would be placed in {} in other languages (e.g. C/C++) can and must be indented. If you indent just random code there will be the error message: unexpected indentation.

Comment: I did but same error i have : IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: ok,thanks but it gives me serial error.However i want to take disconnected message.

Comment: I have updated the answer to even catch that problem.